# How to update based on json keys?

Tags: json, postgresql, key

I have a table of an app setting that looks like this:

```
Code      | Value   |
---------------------
MAC_ADDR  | 'SAMPLE'|
PC_OPT    |   0     |
SHOW_ADDR |   1     |
```

Then I'm receiving a json in my trigger function like this:

```
{MAC_ADDR: 'NEWADDR', PC_OPT: 1, SHOW_ADDR: 0}
```

How do I perform an update based on all the keys from my json?

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `json_populate_record`, eg:

```
t=# create table tj("MAC_ADDR" text, "PC_OPT" int, "SHOW_ADDR" int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into tj select 'SAMPLE',0,1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from tj;
 MAC_ADDR | PC_OPT | SHOW_ADDR
----------+--------+-----------
 SAMPLE   |      0 |         1
(1 row)

t=# update tj set "MAC_ADDR"=j."MAC_ADDR", "PC_OPT"=j."PC_OPT", "SHOW_ADDR"=j."SHOW_ADDR"
from json_populate_record(null::tj,'{"MAC_ADDR": "NEWADDR", "PC_OPT": 1, "SHOW_ADDR": 0}') j
where true;
UPDATE 1
t=# select * from tj;
 MAC_ADDR | PC_OPT | SHOW_ADDR
----------+--------+-----------
 NEWADDR  |      1 |         0
(1 row)
```

keep in mind - you did not specify PK or other column to update rows so all rows will be updated in example above. Which suits your data sample, but would not in case of more data

**Update**

I misunderstood the question, in `(code, value)` table it's even easier, eg:

```
update some_tbl 
  set "Value" = '{"MAC_ADDR": "NEWADDR", "PC_OPT": 1, "SHOW_ADDR": 0}'::json->'MAC_ADDR' 
where "Code"='MAC_ADDR'
```

o again, using the code above you can map update with json keys...

Comment: my table columns are `Code` & `Value`

Comment: thanks for the update, but do you have a way to loop through each json key & while performing an update at the same time? There will be tons of rows to be added soon.